# Show notification from list form on list view

Tags: 2013, javascript, list-view, list-form, notifications

I have a custom display/edit form for my list. After the form is submitted and the user is redirected back to list view, I want to show a notification that 'new item has been added' or 'changes were successfully saved'. I was thinking about using the `SP.UI.Status` or `SP.UI.Notify`, but not sure how to use that on list view. Perhaps some js web part and a query string parameter to determine if notification should be added?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Query String Parameter.

Add query string `Status=Saved` or `Status=Update`

Now use below JavaScript code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var param = getParameterByName("Saved");

    if(Status == "Saved") {
        SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("new item has been added", false);
    }
    else if(Status == "Update") {
        SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("changes were successfully saved", false);
    }
});

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```